# Sum duplicated rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Sum repeated values in datatable (VB.NET) or in SQL Server (are better one or other solutions)

I have a database in which are reported repeated rows:

```
Description | Price | Q.ty | Tax
AAAAAAAAAAA | 10.00 | 20.0 | 5
AAAAAAAAAAA | 10.00 | 12.0 | 5
BBBBBBBBBBB | 18.00 | 09.0 | 5
BBBBBBBBBBB | 18.00 | 12.0 | 5
CCCCCCCCCCC | 13.00 | 15.0 | 5
AAAAAAAAAAA | 17.0  | 19.0 | 5
```

And I want obtain something like this:

```
Description | Price | Q.ty | Tax
AAAAAAAAAAA | 10.00 | 51.0 | 5
BBBBBBBBBBB | 18.00 | 21.0 | 5
CCCCCCCCCCC | 13.00 | 15.0 | 5
```

I've created a datatable in VB.NET and I tried to sum values in it, and then show summed rows in a datagridview, but without results. Then, I've tried to do this with SQL Server (2019), without results again.

Can someone help me, please?

My code is:

```
Dim conn as New SqlConnection("*****")
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT Description, Price, SUM(Q.ty), Tax, FROM Prodotti GROUP BY Descrizione", conn)
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
da.SelectCommand = cmd2
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Clear()
da.Fill(dt)
DataGridView1.SuspendLayout()
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.ResumeLayout()
conn.Close()
```

I want to obtain my goal with VB.NET or directly with SQL Server.

Comment: What should happen if the Tax value is different for two rows with the same Description? Or the Price (as in the first and last rows of the sample data)?

Comment: FYI, they are *rows* not "records".

Comment: What is your goal and how did you decide that Item "AAAAAAAAAAA" should be included with a price of 10.00 when the three related rows do not **all** have that value? The same question applies to Tax column if that value can vary for each transaction.

Comment: Side points: your connection, command and adapter/reader need `Using` blocks

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised that your SQL query runs as you've got a couple syntax errors in there.  There is an extra "," after Tax and the Groupby clause should include Price and Tax, or exclude them from the selected field list

Comment: @Hursey I think that is the point: it doesn't run

Comment: @AndrewMorton i have 100 invoices, which shows products (description), price, q.ty and tax: i have 3 invoices which contains repeated products (description),  with different q.ty (i don't know the reason, suppliers are crazy, maybe), so i need sum q.ty, if the product is the same in that specific invoice. If invoice n. 1234 contains "jeans" 2 times (q.ty 5 units and 10 units) and t-shirts 1 time, (3 units) i need to obtain: jeans 15 units and  t-shirts 3 units.

Comment: I need "only" sum q.ty, if description is the same, using VB.NET. Thank you in advice :)

Comment: If there is a dot in the name of the column, you will need to write it as `[Q.ty]`. Using dots in column names is a bad idea as it could cause confusion - Q.ty would usually mean column ty of table Q.

Comment: I changed column name from Q.ty to Qty, but SQL give me error :/

Answer (score 0):

Given this table and data:

```sql
USE [Testing]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SO71561140]    Script Date: 26/03/2022 19:01:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SO71561140](
    [Description] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Tax] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SO71561140] ([Description], [Price], [Quantity], [Tax]) VALUES (N'A         ', CAST(10 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(20 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(19, 4)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SO71561140] ([Description], [Price], [Quantity], [Tax]) VALUES (N'A         ', CAST(10 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(12 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(19, 4)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SO71561140] ([Description], [Price], [Quantity], [Tax]) VALUES (N'B         ', CAST(18 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(9 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(19, 4)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SO71561140] ([Description], [Price], [Quantity], [Tax]) VALUES (N'B         ', CAST(18 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(12 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(19, 4)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SO71561140] ([Description], [Price], [Quantity], [Tax]) VALUES (N'C         ', CAST(13 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(15 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(19, 4)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SO71561140] ([Description], [Price], [Quantity], [Tax]) VALUES (N'A         ', CAST(17 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(19 AS Decimal(19, 4)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(19, 4)))
GO
```

and this small program:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Sub X()
        Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder() With {.DataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS",
                                                          .InitialCatalog = "Testing",
                                                          .IntegratedSecurity = True}

        Dim sql = "
SELECT [Description], SUM([Quantity]) AS 'Quantity', SUM([Quantity] * [Price]) AS 'Total Price', [Tax]
FROM SO71561140
GROUP BY [Description], [Tax]
"

        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Using conn = New SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString),
               cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn),
                da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            da.Fill(dt)

        End Using

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        X()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I got this result:

[image: Image of datagridview with the result of the SQL query.]

You would need to include the tax rate in the total price per item to be able to remove the tax rate from the displayed data, but that may or may not be a good idea depending on what is needed by whoever pays the bills.